# How long does the Truffle take to move in after building the mushroom biome?

Tags: ps-vita, terraria-console

I currently find myself in a pickle because even after I've built the mushroom biome and met all other requirements, the Truffle NPC won't move in.

- I've defeated not only the Wall of Flesh but Ocram already.
- Created a surface mushroom biome.
- Built a house made out of mushrooms with mushroom furniture.

I have no idea how long it takes for the NPC to move in or if I'm wrong in any of the steps.

[image: The House in the mushroom biome]
[image: How the biome looks in the map]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't easy to tell if the biome you are in is surface or not because of the walls behind the house, I suggest breaking all of that. Also, as it states in the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Truffle), "to get the Truffle to move in, there must be housing in a surface Mushroom Biome during hardmode." judging by the list you have provided you have done all of the things that are required. All that's left is to see if the house you built is even suitable for NPC's.

As it states under the [NPC](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC) section of the wiki, a suitable housing has:

- Proper Lighting
- Enclosed frame composed of blocks, a door, and walls. ([Size](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Home): About 5x12 blocks)
- 1 Flat Surface Item (Ex: Table, Dresser, Bathtub, Bookcase, Workbench, Piano)
- 1 Comfort Item (Ex: Chair, Throne, Bench, Sofa, Bed)

From the pictures you gave, the program might be mistaking your Surface biome as an underground one because of the excess grass walls or not enough lighting. Another thing might be the height of the room.

If nothing works, just have a little patience, NPC's sometimes take a while to move in. Also, just try to preoccupy yourself with something else while waiting to help pass the time. Another thing, those walls inside the house must be player placed, if they spawned that way (Which I doubt, but doesn't hurt to inform you) you need to remove them.

**Please Note:** that there is a bug where if you killed the boss Plantera before the Truffle moving in, he will not move in and you will need to make a new world

Comment: The house is suitable, the biome itself is working since the music changes, all I have left to try is the natural walls around the house, that sounds like something that could happen. I'll give it a try and report back :)

Comment: @Ozmah Alright, don't forget the patience factor, may I ask how long you have waited for the Truffle NPC to spawn before posting this question? Also, note that my answer came from experiences on the PC, idk if it will transfer to the ps-vita

Comment: @Ozmah So did it work?

Comment: I've waited a long time, I built houses for all the hardmode bosses right after I took out The Destroyer (the first hard mode boss I beat). And I'm about to test it in a few minutes :)

Comment: As of right now after clearing the background and even building a mini biome in a floating island with everything made out of mushrooms. 6 in-game days have passed and nothing has happened.

Comment: @Ozmah Two things, I just read some bugs with the Truffle, apparently if you kill plantera before he spawns, the truffle won't spawn. Also, what version Terraria do you have? If it is below 1.2 (Not 1.1.2) then the truffle won't spawn no matter what

Comment: I have the latest Vita version, which is 1.2.1 if I'm not mistaken. Regarding plantera then I may be screwed, I'll have to try in another world :/ let me give that a try.

Comment: Finally! it finally moved in! I had to create another world and started gathering all NPCs again, I did not kill Plantera but killed every other Mechanical Boss. Took a while (around 4 to 6 days) but it finally moved in.

Comment: @Ozmah Gratz man! I edited the answer to better fit your solution

Comment: Could be, the only problem I see with that theory is that I think the Truffle would leave after you kill Plantera.

Comment: @Ozmah Maybe he is oblivious and he doesn't have a newspaper at his new home? OR, maybe since he has seen the player already and sees you as a (maybe) kind soul he will tolerate the god killing heathen in you. Or maybe quite the opposite, maybe we are all holding our npcs hostage....

Comment: Hahahaha that last theory could be right hahaha

Comment: @Ozmah Just a little comment to say that it was quite fun solving the problem with you. By far my most achieving answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem for a while. i've builded over 4 houses and on the fifth one he came. The problem can be:

1. The surface mushroom biome you made dosen't have at least 100 mushroom-themed blocks and plants(e.g. 100 Mushroom Grass & Glowing Mushrooms)
2. The house is too close to Crimson/Corruption. Get rid of it with Dryad's Purification Powder
3. The Surface Mushroom Biome is not clearly an only-biome(e.g. other biomes are in it like in your photo)

I made some houses and it worked well. Here's how they worked:

I builded with 60 Mushroom Walls and covered the edges with glowing Mushrooms.

I put a chair and table close to each other.

I put the Torch on the corner of the wall.

If you're confused of how i made the houses(wich you may be), check the photo i put.

If what i told you worked, good luck with whatever you're doing. And if something isn't working, tell me.[image]

Comment: I was too close to the corruption. Thanks.

Answer (score -7):

Your unlucky because I see walls that means its below ground level I suggest making a bridge in the sky of mud and clentaminating it p.s I don't own terraria on xbox