# I can't get my truffle to move in terraria iOS it just won't?

Tags: terraria-mobile

My truffle won't move in I have beaten ocram even and it still hasn't moved in. I made an overground mushroom biome but nothing is happening. It just keeps saying "maitake would like to settle in". SOS PLS HELP! I don't have pics but I can describe it to you: it is a skybridge 3 blocks thick around 150 blocks really really long has 2 house still vacant and the truffle won't still move in!

Please help once again. I have been trying for 2 days

Comment: 2 real life days not 2 terraria days

Comment: This might be one of the most asked questions on the site, I suggest typing [Truffle into the search or just clicking these words](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=truffle), although I think it's [this question and answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177934/how-long-does-the-truffle-take-to-move-in-after-building-the-mushroom-biome?s=8|1.0048) that are the most helpful.

Comment: Yeah.i know I tried every one of them. It did not work and most of them are not for terraria iOS i seriously need help to get the truffle to move in I just don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Yeah dude I went through ur list nothing comes up with an answer I have tried several ways none work

Comment: I know it is a duplicate question but all the other questions answers never work!