# Why won't Amanita move in and settle down?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I keep getting an alert that Amanita would like to settle down. I have a house ready for them however they still won't move in. Who is this NPC and why won't they settle down?

Comment: Amanita is one of the names that the [Truffle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Truffle)  NPC can spawn with. This NPC requires a different house to most, see above ground mushroom biome for more info.

Comment: These are recurrent questions in the Terraria section, you can look at [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177934/how-long-does-the-truffle-take-to-move-in-after-building-the-mushroom-biome) to see a complete answer about why the Truffle NPC might not settle down in your world.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an above-ground glowing mushroom biome in order to make the Truffle move in.

Comment: Above ground mushroom biome is not possible in pocket edition